# About systems of equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

About  systems of equations, what is the relation between the system of polynomial equations $f_1=\cdots=f_n=0$ and the system $(f_1-y_1)=\cdots=(f_n-y_n)=0$ , where $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ belong to $C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are new variables? Any information about second kind of systems will help. And what are the useful references? I need some.